# Generating medium/large amount of random data correctly

Tags: linux, random

I'm running on Linux.
Say I'm working on a webapplication that needs to assign a random hard to guess session-token with every request. Lets say the session token should be 32 random bytes for every successfully created session.

What would be the ideal way to generate the session-token?
It's important that its not deterministic, as that would mean others could hijack the session.
Reading from /dev/urandom comes to mind.

However, the manpage of random(and urandom) for linux states:

> While some safety margin above that minimum is reasonable, as a guard
>   against flaws in the CPRNG algorithm, no cryptographic primitive
>   available today can hope  to  promise  more than  256 bits of
>   security, so if any program reads more than 256 bits (32 bytes) from
>   the kernel random pool per invocation, or per reasonable reseed
>   interval (not less than one minute), that should be taken as a sign
>   that its cryptography is not skilfully implemented.

I guess this means that, if I generate more than 1 user-session pr minute, I violate this guideline.
Is there a reason for this guideline, beyond the fact that eating too much of /dev/urandom results in it becoming possibly "less" random and more relying on the CPRNG, for other programs running on the computer?

What's the recommended way of doing this? Read a smaller number of random bits from /dev/urandom, and using them to seed(and possibly reseeding on an interval) a custom widely adpopted and reasonable secure RNG used by my application? (If so, there is a fine line between just reading it all from /dev/urandom and its CPRNG, right?)

Comment: Isn't this what `/dev/random` is for? That will block, IIRC, if the kernel runs out of entropy.

Comment: @larsmans I'm afraid that would be a horrible idea. If I had any significant number of concurrent users, they would deplete the entropy pool and the entire webservice would become unresponsive.
I had a good read about urandom vs random, yesterday, here:
http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/

Comment: Just two paragraphs about your quote (it's from `man random(4)`) I read `The kernel random-number generator is designed to  produce  a  small  amount  of high-quality  seed material to seed a cryptographic pseudo-random number generator (CPRNG).`  In my understanding this means that the answer to your penultimate question is YES, provided `s/urandom/random/`

Comment: That's cool. Thanks for pointing it out gboffi...that'll teach me not get get lazy and stop reading the manpage once I face challenges.
However, It's still a bit unclear, why should I use my own CPRNG, instead of just reading it all from urandom(which is indeed a non-blocking CPRNG). The fact that we make it less secure for other random-consumers in the system and sort of exposes a "single point of failure/insecurity" comes to mind, but still, I have no clue about this.

Comment: I would use a stream cipher like Salsa20 seeded with 32 bytes read from /dev/random.